# Open the loop in voltage-current feedback

Tags: feedback

The following is a figure from 8.61 in [*Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit*](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf), page 311:

[image]

Here is the question: Calculate feedback \$\beta\$ of the following circuit:

[image]

As we use the method of the book, we have to ground both of two terminal feedback network of the loop according to figure 8.61:

[image: strong text]

$$\beta = \frac{V_{out}} {I_{in}} = R_2 \parallel R_3$$

However,  professor Ali Hajimiri on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/lWjGSSr_uMo?list=PLc7Gz02Znph-c2-ssFpRrzYwbzplXfXUT&t=3568) thinks the following:

$$H_{\infty} = \frac{1} {g_{m1}} (1 + \frac{R_2} {R_2})$$

Comment: Your feedback network is wrong. Where is the current summing point?

Comment: @internet The feedback network is composed of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$

Comment: You should also include M1 in the feedback network.

Comment: @internet I have never seen a feedback network with active component like transistor. The transistor are comprised of passive components for most of time.

Can you draw correct feedback network in the answer section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would break the loop for the voltage-current feedback.The feedback network includes R1, R2, and the transistor M1.
[image]